Topology for the resolution of identity equality
Let $H$ be a Hilbert space with orthonormal basis $\{x_{n}\}_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. Given $x \in H$, one can write:
$$x = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}\langle x_{n},x\rangle x_{n}. \tag{1}\label{1}$$
Roughly speaking, this identity means that the identity operator satisfies:
$$I = \sum_{n\in \mathbb{N}}|x_{n}\rangle\langle x_{n}|, \tag{2}\label{2}$$
where $|x_{n}\rangle\langle x_{n}|$ projects onto the subspace spanned by $x_{n}$. More rigorously, for every $x \in H$ we have:
$$\bigg{\|}\bigg{(}I - \sum_{n=1}^{N}|x_{n}\rangle\langle x_{n}|\bigg{)}x\bigg{\|} \to 0 \tag{3}\label{3}$$
as $N \to \infty$, which is just a immediate consequence of my first formula (\ref{1}). This shows that the resolution of the identity formula (\ref{2}) holds in the strong topology sense (i.e. $T_{n} \to T$ iff $T_{n}x \to Tx$ for every $x \in H$).
My question is: does (\ref{2}) also hold in the norm topology? Usually I see this formula in books, and I know what it means operationally, but now I am a bit confused what the infinite sum in the right hand side of (\ref{2}) means in terms of topology.

No, (2) can never hold in the norm topology. In more detail, suppose $V$ is an inner product space and that $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ is an infinite orthonormal set. Then, for any finite set $F\subset I$, the complement is non-empty (since $F$ is finite and $I$ is not); fix an index $j\in I\setminus F$. Then (since $x_j$ is a unit vector) we have
\begin{align}
\left\|I-\sum_{i\in F}\langle x_i,\cdot\rangle x_i\right\|\geq
\left\|x_j-\sum_{i\in F}\langle x_i,x_j\rangle x_i\right\|= \|x_j\|=1,
\end{align}
where we’re considering the operator norm on the LHS. In particular,
\begin{align}
\inf_{\text{$F\subset I$, finite}}\left\|I-\sum_{i\in F}\langle x_i,\cdot\rangle x_i\right\|\geq 1.
\end{align}
Even more particularly, if $I=\Bbb{N}$, then for each $N\in\Bbb{N}$, we have
\begin{align}
\inf_{N\in\Bbb{N}}\left\|I-\sum_{n=1}^N\langle x_n,\cdot\rangle x_n\right\|\geq 1>0.
\end{align}
Since the sequence of operator norms is bounded below by a positive number, it can’t converge to $0$ as $N\to\infty$.
So, the meaning of (2) for an orthonormal basis, is that the partial sums converge to the identity operator in the strong-operator-topology, as you said. But notice that this relies on having $\dim V=\infty$ (for finite-dimensional spaces, all these topologies coincide).
